# Kitty watches TV

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Kitty's proved to be not too brilliant at saving people from things going bang so far, so here's hoping she does better this time.

She has to find the city where the next bomb is hidden and, this time, the powers that be have decided that they will give her as little help as possible.

In the room which appears to be stuck way down in the basement is a sofa and a television. Over in the corner is a pot plant and a sink, with a rather crummy record player and a few battered vinyl singles.

At least she can watch TV  -except every channel seems to be unavailable or a haze of static. That's what you get when you stick the satellite dish way down underground. All she has managed to get so far are the cookery channel, the shopping channel and the entertainment channel.

As 24-hour preparation of food or being sold an array of bizarre products does not appeal, it will have to be Entertainment 24. The channel brings up this message:

```
                            **WELCOME TO ENTERTAINMENT 24**
```

> Your choice of a great selection of modern classic comedies, dramas and reality for the whole families.
>
> The following programmes are currently available. Please make your choice.

```
  HOME IMPROVEMENT      FRIENDS               ROSWELL                   AFTERM*A*S*H
  HIGH CHAPARRAL        BONANZA               DR.QUINN MEDICINE WOMAN   SAVING GRACE       
  MAGNUM PI             DUKES OF HAZZARD      MIAMI VICE                WAYWARD PINES
  HART OF DIXIE         19 KIDS AND COUNTING  BIG LOVE                  PORTLANDIA
  GILMORE GIRLS         THE BIG BANG THEORY   *new*YOUNG SHELDON        AMERICAN DAD!
  THE OFFICE USA        PARKS & RECREATION    THIRD ROCK FROM THE SUN   FAMILY GUY
  SMALLVILLE            THE SOPRANOS          THE WEST WING             AMERICAN GOTHIC
  TRUE BLOOD            JUSTIFIED             THE PRETENDER             THE WIRE 
  NORTHERN EXPOSURE     OUTCAST               QUARRY                    TWILIGHT       
  DAWSON'S CREEK        ONE TREE HILL         CAITLIN'S WAY             MY FRIEND FLICKA
  STAN AGAINST EVIL     MURDER SHE WROTE      IN THE HEAT OF THE NIGHT  MY SECRET IDENTITY
  AS THE WORLD TURNS    NEWHART               HAPPY DAYS                MARY TYLER MOORE
```

Kitty is looking forward to cuddling up with on the sofa with a duvet, a hot chocolate and binge marathons of the excellent series shown, but there's still the matter of discovering where that bomb has been planted...

**STATION NEWSFLASH** *Due to disappointing performances in the sweeps, Caitlin's Way has been replaced by Angel Falls and Quarry has been replaced by Memphis Beat. Due to contractual problems, Happy Days will be replaced by That 70s show. We hope this does not affect Kitty's viewing pleasure.*

Answer (score 2):

This information may well be almost 6 years too late for Kitty to make an impact, but I believe the bomb is hidden in:

> **LAS VEGAS** (a.k.a. 'Sin City')

Why? Because looking at the list of shows (and movie series, in the case of *Twilight*) I started to notice a unique property connecting each listed item...

> Every single one of these is set in **a different US state** (or federal district, in the case of *The West Wing*, set in the White House in Washington DC).

These are as follows:

> ```
>  MICHIGAN      NEW YORK       NEW MEXICO  MISSOURI
>  ARIZONA       NEVADA         COLORADO    OKLAHOMA
>  HAWAII        GEORGIA        FLORIDA     IDAHO
>  ALABAMA       ARKANSAS       UTAH        OREGON
>  CONNECTICUT   CALIFORNIA     TEXAS       VIRGINIA
>  PENNSYLVANIA  INDIANA        OHIO        RHODE ISLAND
>  KANSAS        NEW JERSEY     #DC#        SOUTH CAROLINA
>  LOUISIANA     KENTUCKY       DELAWARE    MARYLAND
>  ALASKA        WEST VIRGINIA  TENNESSEE   WASHINGTON
>  MASSACHUSETTS NORTH CAROLINA MONTANA     WYOMING
>  NEW HAMPSHIRE MAINE          MISSISSIPPI NORTH DAKOTA
>  ILLINOIS      VERMONT        WISCONSIN   MINNESOTA
> ```

> (Further proof that this is important is shown by each of the show 'swaps' mentioned in the question involving two shows from the same state. Also, note that while *[My Secret Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Secret_Identity)* is predominantly set in Toronto, Canada, for some reason on the web it is commonly connected with North Dakota - hence its use here - causing much consternation on various message boards, like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/2lys1v/til_there_has_been_a_tv_show_set_in_every_us_state/) on Reddit...)

Looking at this list of 48 items...

> ...there are 3 missing: South Dakota, Iowa, and Nebraska.

What are we to do with this information? I propose that...

> ...we take their initial letters, which spell out **SIN** (a substring further clued by some of the objects listed as being in the room, including the **sin**k and the vinyl **sin**gles).
>
>  Which US city does this point towards? That would be **[Las Vegas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas)**, known by its nickname **Sin City** (fittingly for the puzzle's context, also [a movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_City_(film))).

Kitty had better let someone know qui- Ah, she might be too late by now...

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> 1120 SW Fifth Avenue, Portland, OR 97204?

Reason:

> Each column displaying the television programs may contain a hint to the bomb's location. Unfortunately I am not that familiar with US (or Europe) television networks, their programming options or locations within these regions and thus my response is a guess based on my knowledge for the above-mentioned. I have used the following television programming options (1 per column) to reach my conclusion: "The Office USA", "Parks & Recreation", "The West Wing" and "Portlandia". This can be interpreted as The Office of Parks and Recreation, The West Wing (of the building (if applicable)), Portland. The address mentioned in my answer above is the address of Portland's Parks & Recreation office/s.

Additional information:

I do not know if Kitty's present location is pertinent to finding the solution to where the bomb is. Underground satellite dish installations are rare for residential/consumer applications and if a satellite television network's dish is installed underground; it will need to be in line of sight of a relay dish that is connected to another dish within line of sight of the television network's satellite.

Furthermore, having a potted plant by a sink may indicate that there is a window to the outside. Washing areas in kitchens are commonly placed near windows and if it is an actual (non synthetic) plant; it will require sunlight.

Though, if the room extends above ground level; I do not see any reason for the installation of a dish below ground. The dish may also be placed in front of the window in order to establish a line of sight.

Comment: Why do you think this is the answer?

Comment: Yes, please give an explanation for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bomb is planted

> on top of the rightmost column (AFTERM*A*S*H)

Reason:

> It's on several lists of failed TV shows, and also on Time magazine’s list of the "100 worst ideas of the century". So, definitely a bomb.

Answer (score -1):

> Coober Pedy, South Australia

Because:

> "Programmes" suggests a UK origin.  The channel line-up suggests an English speaking area. And an underground satellite dish jokingly (?) suggests being underground. Mention of a satellite dish also suggests she is not in a major urban area where cable is available.  Coober Pedy meets these criteria - it's a small underground city in South Australia.

Counter Indications:

> I'm not sure about hot chocolate and a duvet in a city built underground to escape the heat.

Answer (score -2):

Answer:

> The bomb is in the basement.

Reasoning:

> Within the puzzle it mentions a "pot plant" and at the end of the puzzle it refers to the bomb being "planted". It could be a play on words.

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers if you don't need to.